# Keep subdirectory structure when installing

Tags: directory, makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have a project with two files: `a/foo` and `b/foo`.

configure.ac:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([test], [1.0], [a@a.a])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Makefile.am

```
EXTRA_DIST = a b
pkgdata_DATA = a/foo b/foo
```

When I run `make install`, I expect make to install `/usr/share/test/a/foo` and `/usr/share/test/b/foo`, but instead, it tries to install both `a/foo` and `b/foo` into `/usr/share/test`, which results in a conflict.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
nobase_pkgdata_DATA = a/foo b/foo
```

The `nobase` prefix tells Automake not to strip the path components from the filenames when installing.